# Scrapy runs but doesnt output anything

Tags: python, scrapy

I am new to scrapy, 
I am trying to get a product information from sephora.
Ideally, I want to get through all skincare, though I am having difficulties on the first stage.
I am trying to figure why this does not yiled any information?
Separately the response arguments in scrapy shell get me the data I need.

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy


class sephora_try_mousturizer(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'sephora_m'
    allowed_domains = ['www.sephora.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.sephora.com/product/the-true-cream-aqua-bomb-P394639?icid2=top-rated:p394639:product//']

def parse(self, response):

        brand = response.css(".css-15zphjk::text").extract()

        title = response.css('css-r4ddnb::text').extract()
        print(title)
        price = response.css(".css-n8yjg7::text").extract()
        ingridinets = response.css(".css-192qj50::text").extract()


        for item in zip(brand,title,price,ingridinets):

            scraped_info = {
                'brand' : item[0],
                'title' : item[1],
                'price' : item[2],
                'ingridinets' : item[3],
            }
            #print (scraped_info)

            #yield or give the scraped info to scrapy
            yield scraped_info
```

The response I get is the following.

```
scrapy crawl sephora_m
2018-11-23 13:00:05 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.5.1 started (bot: sephora_try_mousturizer)
2018-11-23 13:00:05 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.2.5.0, libxml2 2.9.8, cssselect 1.0.3, parsel 1.5.1, w3lib 1.19.0, Twisted 18.9.0, Python 3.6.7 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Oct 23 2018, 14:01:38) - [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)], pyOpenSSL 18.0.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.1a  20 Nov 2018), cryptography 2.4.1, Platform Darwin-18.0.0-x86_64-i386-64bit
2018-11-23 13:00:05 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings: {'BOT_NAME': 'sephora_try_mousturizer', 'FEED_FORMAT': 'csv', 'FEED_URI': 'sephora_m.csv', 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'sephora_try_mousturizer.spiders', 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True, 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['sephora_try_mousturizer.spiders']}
2018-11-23 13:00:05 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.memusage.MemoryUsage',
 'scrapy.extensions.feedexport.FeedExporter',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2018-11-23 13:00:05 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2018-11-23 13:00:05 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2018-11-23 13:00:05 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2018-11-23 13:00:05 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2018-11-23 13:00:05 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2018-11-23 13:00:05 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6024
2018-11-23 13:00:06 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.sephora.com/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2018-11-23 13:00:06 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.sephora.com/product/the-true-cream-aqua-bomb-P394639?icid2=top-rated:p394639:product//> (referer: None)
[]
2018-11-23 13:00:06 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2018-11-23 13:00:06 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 550,
 'downloader/request_count': 2,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 2,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 62260,
 'downloader/response_count': 2,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 2,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2018, 11, 23, 11, 0, 6, 638657),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 3,
 'log_count/INFO': 7,
 'memusage/max': 51142656,
 'memusage/startup': 51142656,
 'response_received_count': 2,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2018, 11, 23, 11, 0, 5, 901156)}
2018-11-23 13:00:06 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

But the output file is still empty.

Comment: Does print (scraped_info) work? If the answer is yes, the problem could be in the pipeline. If not, the problem is in the parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a dot in your css selector for `title`.

This causes `title` to be an empty list, and `zip()` with an empty list will give you nothing.

Answer (score 0):

`zip()` works on given iterables, if any iterable is empty list it will return empty. You haven't added `.` in title selector `css-r4ddnb::text` which cause empty list.